# Information doesn't refresh after clicking on link in AngularJS. I've got {{ value }} but not the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular app that takes information from few JSON files.
The first JSON file contains data about cities and managers. Like this:

```
[
    {
        "link" : "veliky_novgorod",
        "city" : "Великий Новгород",
        "manager" : "mr. Sminth",
    },
    {
        "link" : "magnitogorsk",
        "city" : "Магнитогорск",
        "manager" : "mr. Young",
    },...
```

I use it in order to create a page for every city.
My urls look like this: `...index.html#/cities/veliky_novgorod/`, `...index.html#/cities/biisk/`, `...index.html#/cities/biisk/mobile/`, etc.

Everything works fine, but when I try to go from one page to another information from the other JSON (scopes) doesn't load. After changing page I've always got `{{ value }}`
But when I make refresh manually, everything is going back to normal.
In other words, how can I reload new page after clicking on link. I tried to use `window.location.reload()` But it doesn't work.

```
 <li ng-repeat="city in cities">
    <a href="#/cities/{{city.link}}" ng-click="reloadRoute()">{{city.manager}}</a>
</li>
```

My module and controller below:

```
var curryApp = angular.module('CurryApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'curryControllers'
]);


curryApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'link_list.html',
        controller: 'CurryListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/cities/:cityId/', {
        templateUrl: 'template-total.html',
        controller: 'CurryDetailCtrl'
      }).
      when('/cities/:cityId/mobile/', {
        templateUrl: 'template-mobile.html',
        controller: 'CurryMobileCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

That's my controller:

```
var curryControllers = angular.module('curryControllers', []);

curryControllers.controller('CurryListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('cities.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.cities = data;
});

}]);

curryControllers.controller('CurryDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$route',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $route) {
    $scope.reloadRoute = function(){window.location.reload();}
    $scope.cityId = $routeParams.cityId;
    $http.get('cities.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.cities = data;
    $http.get('paidbc.json').success(function(data2) {
      $scope.paidBc = data2;

      $scope.isActive = function(item) {
    return item.link === $scope.cityId;

};
});
    });
  }]);

curryControllers.controller('CurryMobileCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.cityId = $routeParams.cityId;
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that is an error related with the `href` attribute. According to [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref):

> The wrong way to write it:
>
> ```
> <a href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>
> ```
>
> The correct way to write it:
>
> ```
> <a ng-href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>
> ```

In your case, use:

```
<a ng-href="#/cities/{{city.link}}" ng-click="reloadRoute()">{{city.manager}}</a>
```

instead of using only `href`.

Comment: unfortunately the problem isn't solved. The first page loads fine (`ng-repeat` works) but after changing url by click I have the same issue. I've got `{{ }}` and `ng-repeat` doesn't work.
I also have amCharts plots they don't load either after changing url